# Replace NaN with nearest value in a series of non-numeric object?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, time-series, nan

I'm using Pandas and Numpy and I'm trying to replace all NaN values in a Series like this one:

```
date                    a
2017-04-24 01:00:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 01:20:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 01:40:00  NaN
2017-04-24 02:00:00  NaN
2017-04-24 02:20:00  [0,1,0]
2017-04-24 02:40:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 03:00:00  NaN
2017-04-24 03:20:00  [0,0,1]
2017-04-24 03:40:00  NaN
2017-04-24 04:00:00  [1,0,0]
```

with the nearest objcet (a Numpy array in this case). The result is:

```
date                    a
2017-04-24 01:00:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 01:20:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 01:40:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 02:00:00  [0,1,0]
2017-04-24 02:20:00  [0,1,0]
2017-04-24 02:40:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 03:00:00  [1,0,0]
2017-04-24 03:20:00  [0,0,1]
2017-04-24 03:40:00  [0,0,1]
2017-04-24 04:00:00  [1,0,0]
```

Does someone know an efficient method to do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

drop nulls then fill back up with [**`reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
df.set_index('date').a.dropna().reindex(df.date, method='nearest').reset_index()

                 date          a
0 2017-04-24 01:00:00  [1, 0, 0]
1 2017-04-24 01:20:00  [1, 0, 0]
2 2017-04-24 01:40:00  [1, 0, 0]
3 2017-04-24 02:00:00  [0, 1, 0]
4 2017-04-24 02:20:00  [0, 1, 0]
5 2017-04-24 02:40:00  [1, 0, 0]
6 2017-04-24 03:00:00  [0, 0, 1]
7 2017-04-24 03:20:00  [0, 0, 1]
8 2017-04-24 03:40:00  [1, 0, 0]
9 2017-04-24 04:00:00  [1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: It's what I'm searching for. I'm using `df.reset_index()` before and `df.set_index("timestamp") after your line because `date` is and index, otherwise I have a key error on `date`. What do you think?